# jquery animate append

Tags: jquery, html, swap, onmouseclick

i got a working code of sortable div.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="a" class="insidebox">A</div>
  <div id="b" class="insidebox">B</div>
  <div id="c" class="insidebox">C</div>
  <div id="d" class="insidebox">D</div>
</div>

var $initial = $('.insidebox');
$('.insidebox').click(function(){
    $(this).parent()
         .append( $initial.not(this) );
});​
```

or see here: http://jsfiddle.net/dsnegi/WTTyB/2/
however i am not able to get its id and instead of a quick swap, i would like to have smooth animation.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what animation you want, but you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/WTTyB/3/

Comment: hey thanks, actually i want to use .animate() with it so that it animate to the parent div position.